# What are possible situations where I get a LASTINPUTINFO even if I do not touch the keyboard or mouse?

Tags: c++, timeout, user-input, msdn

I use `GetLastInputInfo()` to get the `LASTINPUTINFO` and check for idleness. This is used for client timeout in my program. Halfway through the set duration for timeout, a dialog will be displayed with a countdown.

It worked properly until now but recently, the timeout either doesn't happen or takes longer because once the dialog is displayed, 1-2 seconds in I will get a new event from `GetLastInputInfo()` and the timer will reset.

I've tried this multiple times and made sure I touched nothing but it still happens. Maybe it's worth noting, it only happens in some environments. In one computer there is never a problem and it proceeds to timeout properly. But in another, it will occur 100%.

I tried adding a `GetMessage()` check and found that a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message is received at the time the timer is reset. I didn't move the mouse, though. I did find information that `WM_MOUSEMOVE` messages may be sent multiple times even if the mouse is not moving and that's why the position should be checked with the previous position. Is this somehow related to why I get a `LASTINPUTINFO`? For 30 seconds I do nothing and suddenly, a random WM_MOUSEMOVE appears.

It happens almost immediately after the countdown dialog is displayed so, by any chance, is a `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message sent when a dialog is displayed? If so, why did this not happen before? Was it just luck on the timing?

Are there other possible causes as to why I get new input events even if I am nowhere near the mouse/keyboard/computer in general?

Comment: For me, it sounds like your mouse sends events although you don't touch it. Possible? Yes. The sensors in the mouse H/W may be in a state where some jittering occurs. Thus, it jumps for and back by one "step". Thus you probably will not notice on screen but your computer/OS does. (I always observed this effect with my mouse at home but never with the one in my office...) To prove whether I'm right you may also check the quantity of movement when evaluating the `WM_MOUSEMOVE`. And this might also provide the workaround - filtering away movements until a certain threshold.

Comment: @Scheff I already considered the possibility of my mouse sending events despite no physical touch from the user (as I've noted in my post). The position does not change so adding a threshold (no matter how big) does not help my case. Thanks, though!

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed that specific part. I agree to forget about the threshold and to use the workaround you already described. May be, the note about the mouse H/W and jittering was valuable at least...

Comment: Could it be [adaptive display](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20090820-00/?p=17043/) feature?